# Set-cookie in response header but not set in browser

Tags: typescript, express, cookies, graphql, apollo-server

I built a GraphQL server using `apollo-server-express`, and run it on localhost:4000.

When I pass the query from GraphQL playground, the response has set-cookie in the header as below:
[response header](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eZixb.gif)

But in storage > cookies tab in chrome, there are no cookies.
[chrome: application > storage > cookies](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jeJA8.png)

Here is my server.ts. (I think I set my `cors` config in correct way)

```js
const server = new ApolloServer({
  typeDefs,
  resolvers,
  introspection: true,
  playground: true,
  dataSources: () => ({
    projectAPI: new ProjectAPI(),
  }),
  context: ({ req, res }: { req: Request; res: Response }) => ({ req, res }),
})

const app = express()

/* Parse cookie header and populate req.cookies */
app.use(cookieParser())

app.use(
  cors({
    origin: '*',
    credentials: true, // <-- REQUIRED backend setting
  })
)

app.use((req: any, res: any, next: any) => {
    console.log(req.cookies)
    next()
})

server.applyMiddleware({ app, path: '/' })

if (process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'test') {
  app.listen({ port: 4000 }, () =>
    console.log(` Server ready at http://localhost:4000${server.graphqlPath}`)
  )
}

export { server }
```

And here is my `resolvers.ts`:

```js
export default {
  Query: {
    session: async (_: null | undefined, __: null | undefined, { res }: any) => {
      const response = await fetch(`http://localhost:3000/api/v1/sessions/current_user`, {
        headers: {
          'content-type': 'application/json',
        },
      })

      /** Get session cookie from the response header */
      const sessionCookie = setCookie
        .parse(response.headers.get('set-cookie') as string)
        .find((el: any) => el.name === '_session')

      /** If session cookie exists, save the cookie */
      if (sessionCookie && res) {
        const { name, value, ...rest } = sessionCookie
        res.cookie(name, value, rest)
      }

      const data = await response.json()
      return data.user
    },
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you using apollo-client on the client side?

If so, you need to add the `credentials` option when you create the terminating http link (or batch link etc). If not using apollo-client, you just need to add in this option accordingly.

```
const OPTS = {
  uri: GQL_BASE,
  credentials: 'include', // or 'same-origin' etc.
  includeExtensions: true,
}

const httpLink = new BatchHttpLink(OPTS)
```

You are correct, that you also need `credentials: true` added in the CORS options.